# Can a ‘finally’ block alter a returned value from its ‘try’ block?

Tags: c#

I was expecting obj to be null in the below code as my understanding is that object's are returned by reference. Can someone explain why obj is not null?

```
public class Example
{
    private static ArrayList obj;

    public static ArrayList GetObj()
    {
        try
        {
            obj = new ArrayList();
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            obj = null;
        }
    }
}

public class MainProgram
{
    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        ArrayList obj;
        obj = Example.GetObj(); // Why is obj not null???
    }
}
```

Comment: When you `return obj`, you're returning a reference to your `ArrayList` object, not `obj`.

Comment: OP, this doesn't have anything to do with the answer really, but may interest you: [Ref return in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)

Comment: You are confusing two kinds of references: references to *objects* and references to *variables*.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a useless catch clause in your sample code?  The code would be more clear without it.

Comment: Mystifying code, but I'd assume you hope that the *finally* block modifies the method return value.  Idle hope, the return statement locked it in.  Think of it as making a copy, actually what happens at runtime.  A copy of the object reference, not a copy of the object.  Changing the variable afterwards can't change that copy.

Comment: @HansPassant comment above is the full and correct answer to this question.

Comment: To add to Eric's comment: A catch block containing `throw ex;` is not merely useless; it's actually worse than than no catch block at all.  `throw ex;` resets the stack trace.  Eric discusses this in [Too much reuse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/04/too-much-reuse/).

Comment: @Brian Yes, although it would still be useless, you could avoid this problem by just using `throw`, instead of `throw e`. The `catch` expression in this case would not need to name a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll step you through it with code comments.

```
//This reserves a memory location to store a reference to an ArrayList
private static ArrayList obj;  

public static ArrayList GetObj()
{
    try
    {
        //This instantiates a new ArrayList and stores a reference to it in obj
        obj = new ArrayList();

        //This creates a copy of the reference stored in obj and returns it to the caller
        return obj;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        //This sets the reference stored in obj to null. This does not affect the copy of the reference that was returned earlier
        obj = null;
    }
}

public static void SomeMethod()
{
    //This reserves a different memory location that can store a reference to an ArrayList.
    //Note that this exists in parallel with the static field named obj
    ArrayList obj;

    //This retrieves the reference to the ArrayList that was returned and stores it in the local (not static) variable obj
    obj = Example.GetObj(); 
}
```

In the end, your local variable `obj` receives a copy of the ArrayList reference and is unaffected by the finally block.

Comment: I note that "pushed onto the stack" just confuses matters.  In practice the return value is almost never pushed onto the stack; it's loaded into a register, typically EAX on x86 architectures. You run the risk of confusing the novice programmer when you describe implementation details as though they were facts, particularly if they are wrong.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert I always appreciate it when you chime in and your answers are very reliable. I would humbly offer the feedback that your bedside manner may suboptimal :)

Comment: Your comment is noted.

Comment: That said, I'm slightly confused by your analogy. If I'm the doctor, then who is the sick patient requiring tender care in this analogy?

Comment: @EricLippert It’s Mr. Wu.

Comment: @EricLippert Based on this exchange, I am going to start a rumor that you're a Vulcan.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: But Mr. Wu is the one who was giving misleading advice to someone seeking aid. In this analogy is he doing that from his sickbed?  I'm confused.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: That's a bad analogy. If we want to make a medical analogy, the original poster is the ailing patient, the person making a misleading answer that confuses the patient is the resident trying to help the patient, and the person correcting the resident's mistakes so as to not harm the patient and teach the resident is the medical preceptor. You don't criticize a preceptor for their bedside manner **because they are not tending a patient**.  They're **training a resident**.  That's a far more apt analogy.

Comment: @GlennSlayden: Regardless of the quality of the analogy, I note that the critique is *responding to tone*.  My suggestion is that everyone here spend more time *making sure their answers are correct, clear and helpful* and less time critiquing tone.  If there were fewer incorrect, misleading, unclear answers then there would be fewer opportunities for taking offense at well-intended corrections.

Comment: On SO, accuracy is important, but [so is congeniality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). @EricLippert, your technical accuracy is beyond reproach, and in case you are working on your soft skills, I am simply offering you a data point. I am not asking you to change for me. The rest of this thread seems like a waste of bandwidth.